# URL Shortcode Is not Printing on href or src in few pages on wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I have created a shortcode for getting the theme url for getting theme specific images,js and css. The resulting page url prints on the page successfully but when i use the shortcode on herf or src it prints the shortcode name instead of url. Eg,

```
    [theme_uri]
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="[theme_uri]css/custom-landing.css"/>
```

output

```
    http://www.example.com/wp-content/themes/modular-child/
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="[theme_uri]css/custom-landing.css">
```

I am using wordpress modular framework, This issue occurred only in few pages. Please help me on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one,

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href=[theme_uri]"css/custom-landing.css">
```